# CURL call results in unexpected response from ASR web service

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

The error below is what I'm getting when I try to use CURL to upload audio samples (from memory) to Nuance's ASR web-service. I'm not sure where the error is in my code, so I'm hoping that somebody can help me spot where the error is. According to the response, the error is an invalid app ID or app key, but I have pasted that app ID and key directly from my Nuance account and checked it several times.

The code is supposed to do the following:

1. Post audio data to Nuance's ASR webservice
2. Get recognition result (text string) from ASR service

My source code looks like this:

```
#include "curl.h"


typedef struct {
    unsigned char* buffer;       
    unsigned int   size;         
    unsigned int   index;
} transfer_state;

struct curl_slist *slist = NULL;
CURL* curl;
int status = 0;
char* audioDataPtr = NULL;
transfer_state read_state, write_state;
unsigned long sizeOfAudioInBytes;
char recognitionResult[4096] = {0};



static size_t read_data(char *bufptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, transfer_state *read_state) {
    size_t read;

    read = min(size * nitems, read_state->size - read_state->index);
    memcpy(bufptr, &(read_state->buffer[read_state->index]), read);
    read_state->index += read;

    return read / size;
}

static size_t write_data (void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, transfer_state *write_state) {

    memcpy(&(write_state->buffer[write_state->index]), ptr, size * nmemb);
    write_state->index += size * nmemb;
    //assert(write_state->index < write_state->size);

    return nmemb;
}

/* Function for loading audio */
unsigned long loadAudioFile(char* audioFileName, char** audioData)
{
   unsigned long sz = 0;

   FILE* fid = fopen(audioFileName, "r");
   fseek(fid, 0L, SEEK_END);
   sz = ftell(fid);
   fseek(fid, 0L, SEEK_SET);
   *audioData = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
   fread((void*) *audioData, 1, sz, fid);
   fclose(fid);

   return sz;
}

void main(void)
{
   int n = 0;
   char* char_ptr = NULL;
   char contentLength[128] = {0};

   sizeOfAudioInBytes = loadAudioFile("audio_16k16bit.pcm", &audioDataPtr);

   read_state.buffer  = (unsigned char*) audioDataPtr;
    read_state.index   = 0;
    read_state.size    = sizeOfAudioInBytes;

    write_state.buffer = (unsigned char*) recognitionResult;
    write_state.index  = 0;
    write_state.size   = 4096;

   curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,  "https://dictation.nuancemobility.net/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation");
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "appId=MYAPPID&appKey=MY128CHARAPPKEY"); 
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   slist = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type:audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000");
   curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Language:ENUS");
   curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept-Language:ENUS");
   curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept:text/plain");
   curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept-Topic:Dictation");

   memset(contentLength,0,128);
   sprintf(contentLength, "Content-Length:%d", sizeOfAudioInBytes);
   curl_slist_append(slist, contentLength);


   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (char*) audioDataPtr);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) (sizeOfAudioInBytes) );
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&write_state);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, (void*)&read_state);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

   status = curl_easy_perform(curl);
   if (status != 0)
   {
      printf("[%s:%d] ERROR. Code: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, status);
   }

    n = write_state.index;
    recognitionResult[n] = 0; // possible problem if n == size!

   /* Locate first occurence of \n */
    char_ptr = strchr(recognitionResult, '\n');
    if (char_ptr != 0) 
   {
      /* Zero terminate string */
        *char_ptr = 0;
    }

   printf("%s\n", recognitionResult);

   free(audioDataPtr);

    curl_slist_free_all(slist);

   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}
```

This is the content that I get back from the server when I execute the C-code above:

> Error 401 Unauthorized, invalid application id
>   or key.
>
> ### HTTP ERROR 401
>
> Problem
>   accessing /NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation. Reason:.
>
> ```
>     Unauthorized,
> invalid application id or key.
> ```
>
> ..

To verify that my ASR account works, I downloaded a curl executable and executed the following command:

curl "https://dictation.nuancemobility.net:443/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation?appId=MYAPPID&appKey=MY128BYTEAPPKEY" -H "Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000" -H "Accept-Language: ENUS" -H "Content-Length:264522" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Accept-Topic: Dictation" -k --data-binary @audio_16k16bit.pcm  -v

and that works fine:

[image: CURL response]

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something very similar, I resolved the problem that you are facing by using the api keys and id received through mail rather then from the http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com

if you could help with the below Error 500:

```
Problem accessing /NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation. Reason:

x-nuance-sessionid*********************************

Received QueryRetry: 6 AUDIO_INFO
```

After resolving this I am getting another error 500 when i post a audio file with codex. Not sure how to resolve it.

Thank you.